# What device allows me to recover a hot wire from two travellers coming from a 3-way switch?

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle

At some spot (call it, say, S1) I have a 3-way switch with two incoming travellers from another 3-way switch downstairs (say, S2) and for some reason I cannot easily rewire things between S1 and S2.

I would need a (full) hot wire at S1 and there is none. So I thought: in theory, at any moment in time, exactly one of the two travellers is hot. Is there some device that I could wire at the end of the two travellers at S1 that would recover a permanent hot wire, switching automatically from one traveller or the other?

[image]

This is S1. The two black wires are the travelers, the two white wires go to two separate lamps (and are bridged).

[image]

Comment: I just described the process of a 3-way switch for @derNincompoop. You might take a look at that.  Otherwise we would need a little more information as to what is in the S1 box and what is in S2 box in the manner of conductors.

Comment: The two 3-way switches work fine. I have no problem with them. I'm just trying to recreate a hot wire from two travellers.

Comment: Will you ever want to install another switch in the middle in the future? It's possible to rewire your existing 3-way setup to let you do this without any extra gadgets, but that forecloses the use of 4-way switching.  Can you also provide photos of the insides of the boxes please?  And where on this planet are you?

Comment: I added some (some kind of primitive) schema. I'm in Switzerland.

Comment: OK, the 4-way switch in the middle complicates things -- now you *will* need a gadget if you can't run more wires...

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the inside of the box at S1, still?  This is possible with a cleverly wired relay I think, but the construction details can get a bit annoying...

Comment: You have not indicated how the neutral is connected from the lamp to the service panel. I should be pass through all the switch boxes.

Comment: I suspect OP merely omitted the neutral wire for illustration.  In most countries the neutral wire would physically travel back through the same cables or raceways.   Could be different in Switzerland, they may not need to run paired neutrals because *the entire country* is neutral!

Comment: I would have responded sooner but I was in the bathroom reacting to @Harper's definition of Swiss neutral.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel There you go. Harper: Nailed it :-) Neutral goes back to S1 then disappears somewhere not near S2 or S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a relay. Some people would delight in a technical solution, while others would not want a non-standard lashup in their house.

Here is one way, using a mains-voltage SPDT relay that is a common industrial catalog item.

[image: monostable SPDT relay]

The activating coil is connected between one of the travelers and the neutral. The normally-open terminal is connected to that same traveler, while the normally-closed terminal is connected to the other traveler. The always-hot may then be drawn from the relay common terminal.

Unfortunately this kind of relay wastes a small amount of power (the holding current) when one of the travelers is hot.

Added in response to comments: A bistable relay does not require a holding current. These are harder to find, and probably will not fit into a residential junction box. If you can find one, you will probably also find instructions for wiring it for your application.

But just in case you find one at a garage sale and the instructions are missing, here is a way to use a bistable DPDT to do what you want.

[image: bistable DPDT relay]

Comment: Very nice. Would a two-coil bistable (Latching)?) relay solve the consumption problem?

Comment: And are these things small enough that I could hide them behind my switch? The ones I find online seem to be pretty large...

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet -- the consumption issue is pretty insignificant (it's a few tens of mA at 120V if even that)

Comment: Good to know. But that doesn’t answer the question: do latching relays also have this holding current issue?

Comment: A mechanically latching two-position relay would not require any holding current. - But I could not find a latching relay in any catalog that would fit into a residential wiring junction box.

Comment: I tried with an SPDT relay and it works well. Thanks a lot for the detailed information and wiring schemas!