# How can I subfeed a single pole switch from a 3-way switch to control a fluorescent light?

Tags: electrical, switch

I have an overhead utility room light that is controlled by two 3-way switches.  I have added a light over the washer and dryer that I'd like to control from a single pole switch.  I could only add the single pole switch to the non directly powered 3 way switch box.  I am okay with the light only coming on with the one 3 way switch being powered on.  How do I do this?  The only thing I have found is how to make it power up when the overhead light is turned off by the 3 way I want to feed it.

Comment: Why can't you run a cable from the box with the always-hot?

Comment: The attic isn't accessible here, and it isn't wired through the walls in a straight line.  I can't get an always hot to the box.

Comment: Add another 3 way to feed the light

Answer (score 2):

That's not so clever. The problem is if the washer light is ON, and the utility room light is OFF, then flipping the farther 3-way will turn the washer light OFF and the utility room light ON, necessitating a trip to the other 3-way to put it right.

---

You need a major reassignment of wire functions in the 3-way circuit.

- Ground is ground
- White is neutral, always
- Black is always-hot, always
- Red is a *digital control line* (or it can be a relay actuation signal line)

The 3-way box that feeds the lamp gets the "master" smart switch (or a 3-way and the relay).  The "remote" smart switch goes in the other 3-way box.  Some smart switches use a data-communication wire, that's what red is for. Others use radio or powerline-induction signaling, in that case red is unused.

Now there's always-hot and neutral in every box regardless of the topology of the 3-way system.   Now you can add the second 1-way switch in the normal fashion for adding a 1-way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.  Definitely weird and maybe not to code.  Basically you want to splice the new supply to **one** of the travelers.  In the diagram below the light will have power only when the supply side 3 way switch is in the up position.

[image: Cad]

As a side note, it would cool if someone made a 3 way switch that had a constant hot connection(for the load side switch).  This should be possible using relays.  It would probably be cost prohibitive but might be useful in certain circumstances.

Comment: That exists.  In this application it's called /4 cable.  Black is always-hot, white is neutral, red/blue are the travelers.  What you have drawn is to code, it's just super strange.

Comment: Per your side note, see this answer https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/116307/what-device-allows-me-to-recover-a-hot-wire-from-two-travellers-coming-from-a-3/116335#116335 for possible relay solutions. - A switch containing such a relay would not be *inherently* expensive, except that its sales volume would be too low to effectively amortize its testing and certification costs.